# How to display two column value in one DetailsView cell

Tags: asp.net, webforms, detailsview

I want to display two column value in one DetailsView cell.

Aspx:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="data">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNo2" HeaderText="Ticket No" SortExpression="TicketNo2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNo" HeaderText="Ticket Serial" SortExpression="TicketNo" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

The above code is showing values in two seperate columns of the DetailsView.
How can I display both values in one column?

Comment: You can send combined value of two columns from sql and show in one column.

Comment: Do you need to keep sorting functionality by separated fields?

Answer (score 0):

I find out the answer to display two column value in one details view cell. Given below code worked for me.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="data">
<Fields>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ticket No" SortExpression="TicketNo2">
<EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TicketNo2") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TicketNo") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: See that you have `<EditItemTemplate>` which should not be there. Also, instead of `Bind` use `Eval` as you are just going to display the information. And last, you may not need the `<asp:Label` controls, you could print directly the evaluated columns.